# C# class design with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a repository class that I want to add two methods to:

```
public IEnumerable<OpenCall> OpenCalls()
{
    return something;
}

public IEnumerable<OpenCall> OpenCalls(DateTime start, DateTime endd)
{
    return something_slightly_different;
}
```

Inside each method I am going to call another method (AverageResolutions()) that returns a list of average resolutions. Obviously this method will also need to take 0 parameters or 2 parameters. The way I'm doing things at the moment I'm either going to end with two almost identical copies of OpenCalls(), or two almost identical copies of AverageResolutions(), altered slightly to allow for the DateTime parameters.

I think I'm doing this wrong - how can I just end up with one version of a method that will either take 0 or 2 parameters and then decide what to call further down the line if they are either null or not null?

Comment: what's happening in OpenCalls ? a call to a db ? just an operation on a list ?

Comment: I don't see any problem.  You could have OpenCalls() just call OpenCalls(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue).

Comment: OpenCalls() makes a call to a method called AverageResolutions() which returns a generic list of type AverageResolution via a DB call. OpenCalls() then makes it's own database call to populate another list, and as part of that populating it searches the AverageResolutions() list based on what comes back from the DB.

Comment: but who need start and end directly ? openCall or AverageResolutions ? and on what type / property are they compared ?

Comment: cause I would suggest to use a parameter like `Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>> predicate = null` . And pass it to something queryable : `var query = db.SomeClasses; if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the method signature to use optional arguments:

```
public IEnumerable<OpenCall> OpenCalls(DateTime? start=null, DateTime? end=null)
{
    if (start.HasValue && end.HasValue)
    {
        return something_slightly_different;
    }
    return something;
}
```

Note that you will need to make the `DateTime`-parameters nullable, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to set default values (which have to be compile-time constants).

For more information about nullable types, and the syntactic sugar (writing `DateTime?` instead of `Nullable<DateTime>` see the [MSDN article on Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For more information about optional parameters see the Optional Arguments section of the [MSDN article about Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: What does the '?' after the first DateTime parameter data type do?

Comment: It denotes the `DateTime` parameters as Nullable types. See [MSDN on Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<OpenCall> OpenCalls()
{
    return OpenCalls(null, null);
}

public IEnumerable<OpenCall> OpenCalls(DateTime? start, DateTime? endd)
{
    //if (!start.HasValue) ... etc.
    return something_slightly_different;
}
```

If this solution is "clever" really depends on your other code. Having dozens of null checks isn´t nice. If you only have to check once or twice, it may be a good solution.
Also, you could use optional parameters.

Comment: The datetime parameters would need to be nullable (DateTime?) for this to work, apart from that, this is how I would do it +1

Comment: Any good SO answer that has a code snippet starts with a quickie VS project that checks if the code compiles.  Avoid taking shortcuts.

Comment: And it's a viable design solution to chain these together? What I mean is that in my code now I go from the public repository method to a private repository method and then to a private static method to fetch a DB query string. Each of these will have nullable start and end datetime parameters and each will do the HasValue check to see if both were populated (or not).

Comment: Edited the code, DateTimes are now nullable. @markp3rry i think you could go with my solution or with Spontifixus´. Personally i don´t like those optional parameters and i try to avoid them, because it (imho) can lead to difficult to read code, but that´s really just my personal opinion.

Comment: -(-1) for making the code compile clean. The code is valid now. I personally prefer the default parameters as shown in my solution, but Jobo's solution will do the trick, too.